# Color profiles conversion

Tags: cmyk, hsv, hsl, color-management, color-profile

I have a project on color profile conversion in C++, where the idea is to use CIELAB as transition between RGB and all others (CMY; CMYK; HSV; HSL;...).But I have one big big problem. I have searched everywhere and I cannot find any formula or descrition how could I convert CIELAB to others(CMY; CMYK; HSV; HSL; ...) only I got is what I found here : http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH&H=14#text14 . Can someone please help me with formula or with an idea how to get to them? Thank you so so much. 
Regards,
magic :)

Comment: It looks like you can go from RGB to XYZ and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but I need CIELAB to CMY, CIELAB to CMYK, CIELAB to HSV and CIELAB to HSL, that means I cannot use RGB to CMY and etc.

Comment: I had a similar need in c#, except I used Rgb as a bridge rather than Lab. It's not C++, but you can get all the conversions here: https://github.com/THEjoezack/ColorMine/tree/master/ColorMine/ColorSpaces/Conversions

Answer (score 1):

Color conversion with mathematical formulas yields very poor results with no serious application. Color systems are far too complex to capture them in simple, closed mathematical formulas let alone in linear formulas.

Good results can only be achived by using color profile files. And the conversion basically invovles interpolation between samples stored in these files.

Have a look at [Little CMS](http://www.littlecms.com/). It probably does everything you need. Or if your software will run on Windows, you can use the built-in [Windows Color System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487409) to do the conversion.

Comment: You want to say that I should use some additional files where I can keep data about colors, like tables of values for every tone of color? And than compare it through the code. Isn't that do much comparison to do? Thank you for suggestions but the idea of my project (what professor asks) is not to use existing software but to make own. I feel pretty helpless in this situation, I have look everywhere, I have nothing else to type in Google and to get new results,I've searched so many links and books and papers.

Comment: These files are called color profiles, have a standarized format (.icc) and are available from companies like Adobe or organizations like ECI (often for free). But since this a student project and you may not use existing software, you'll better go with some formulas. But don't expect too much. The output colors will only remotely resemble the input color.

Comment: but I cannot find those formulas, do you know where to find them, CIELAB->CMY, etc?